# How to use something similar to a constructor for java interfaces?

Tags: java, enums, interface

I am using enums for some data in a program I am writing and would like to use an interface so that I, or another person, can add enums without editing the original code. I have all of the work done, except for being able to get a list of the enums easily. I know that interfaces cannot have constructors, but is there any way to add new instances of the interface to a list? The only way I have been able to do it is to add it to the list in the enum's constructor.

Comment: changing a enum in runtime sound like a terrible idea. Kind of breaks the whole concept with enums

Comment: Can you share some [pseudo] code to make the requirement a tad clearer?

Comment: You need to write a class that implements the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Re: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9

Enums are implicitly final.  They are a unique type; it is like saying class, interface, enum are all treated as individuals, but none can be one another.  An enum can implement an interface, but that's like saying a class (abstract or concrete) can implement an interface.

So, your question (is there any way to add new instances of the interface to a list?) needs to be restated... can you add an enum constant to an enum?  No (as I know it).